# Faster Emails with WP Mail

Tags: performance, wp-mail

I'm using `wp_mail()` to send transactional emails on my website, but it takes very long to process the email. What can I do to speed up this process?

Comment: Difficult question to answer as this could be related to anything and not necessarily the `wp_mail()` function or even WP itself. It could be the transnational provider, it could be your server, it could be a random issue that goes away, it could be your plugins, your theme, or anything in-between causing issue. A vanilla install of WP rarely if ever causes performance issues. What have you done yourself to determine that the issue is with `wp_mail()`?

Comment: You could not use wp_mail and send email via SMTP.